# How can I design a dropdown menu with a draw-down effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am trying to do a dropdown menu with animation.

So far I finished a common dropdown like below example.

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: transparent;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 100;
}


.menu {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
  /* transform: translateY(-100%); */
  /* I want it drawn down behind the button */
}

input:checked+.menu {
  transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

```html
<label for="check">Click me</label>

<input id="check" type="checkbox">

<div class="menu">
  <p>I am dropdown menu</p>
</div>
```

My purpose, however, is to design a menu that can slide down (draw down) behind

the button. I had set the z-index to those elements but not works.

Also, I cannot set the background color to the toggle button, I need to keep it transparent.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check below changes of css making menu element absolute and padding of top

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: transparent;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 100;
}


.menu {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
  position:absolute;
  padding-top:35px;
  border:1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

input:checked+.menu {
  transform: translateY(-40px);
}
```

```html
<label for="check">Click me</label>

<input id="check" type="checkbox">

<div class="menu">
  <p>I am dropdown menu</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want the button can cover the menu before the menu moves over the border of the button.